# unexpected error in trigger when export

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Documentation says that

> There cannot be two triggers for a given table that have the same
>   trigger action time and event.

I use mysql 5.5.16. I created two triggers. `upd_check1` and `sale_tri`. I am sure that my two trigger perform two different tables on `INSERT` event. But why I get this error in both triggers. when I try export database(**phpmyadmin doesn't show error but mysql workbench, heidisql, query browser show error**).

> SQL Error (1235): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple
>   triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

Here my `upd_check1` trigger

```
--
-- Triggers `product_purchases`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `upd_check1`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `upd_check1` AFTER INSERT ON `product_purchases`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE X INTEGER;
  SET X = (SELECT product_id FROM product_stock where product_id = NEW.product_id );
  IF NEW.product_id =X  THEN
  UPDATE
    product_stock AS S,
    product_purchase_item AS I,
    product_purchases AS P
  SET
    S.product_total_quantity=S.product_total_quantity+I.quantity
  WHERE
    S.product_id=I.product_id
  AND
    I.product_purchase_item_id=P.product_purchase_item_id
  AND
    P.product_purchase_id=NEW.product_purchase_id;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO
      product_stock (product_id,product_total_quantity)
    SELECT
      product_id, quantity
    FROM
      product_purchase_item
    WHERE
      product_purchase_item_id=NEW.product_purchase_item_id;
  END IF;

  END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

And Here my `sale tri` trigger

```
--
-- Triggers `product_sales`
--
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `sale_tri`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `sale_tri` AFTER INSERT ON `product_sales`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
       DECLARE X INTEGER;

        SET X = (SELECT product_id FROM product_stock where product_id = NEW.product_id );
        IF NEW.product_id =X THEN
          update product_stock as s,
          product_sale_item as i,
          product_sales as p
        SET s.product_total_quantity=s.product_total_quantity-i.quantity
        WHERE s.product_id=i.product_id AND
           i.product_sale_item_id=p.product_sales_item_id AND
           p.product_sales_id=NEW.product_sales_id;
       END IF;
   END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You sure those tables don't already have triggers on them?

Comment: yea. only above two triggers I use.

Comment: You have an error while *exporting* the DB, or while *importing* ?

Comment: @coder Do you think so or did you confirm with `SHOW TRIGGER` command?

Comment: @fancyPants. I am 100% sure I have 2 triggers. I did check `SHOW TRIGGERS`

Comment: @SylvainLeroux. while exporting. it's no problem when I import. database run well. Even phpmyadmin did export without error. But mysqlworkbench show error  when I try to forward engineering. not reverse engineering

Comment: I note that both triggers can insert or update the product_stock table. Is there any possibility through the workings of foreign keys and/or check constraints that an insert or update in the product_stock table could cause an insert to occur in either the product_purchases or product_sales tables? If this were possible, then in certain circumstances, executing an insert on one of these tables would cause both triggers to fire, and hence the error.

Comment: @JohnBingham tanks for observation. My product_stock table is free of foreign key. So may be there is no cause for data constraint.

Comment: @imran Are both product_purchases and product_sales tables and not views?

Comment: product_purchases and product_sales are both tables. @JohnBingham

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both

```
SHOW TRIGGERS
```

and

```
SELECT * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS
```

only display one AFTER INSERT trigger for each table, the next step is to make sure there is no corruption in the trigger definition itself.

MySQL keeps triggers in `*.TRG` and `*.TRN` files in the data directory, and the format is textual, so a visual inspection can help to verify how many triggers are really defined.

You should see something similar to this for the table:

```
malff@linux-3ezv:test> more product_sales.TRG
TYPE=TRIGGERS
triggers='CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `sale_tri` AFTER INSERT ON `product_sales`\n FOR EACH ROW BEGIN\n       D
ECLARE X INTEGER;\n ... END'
sql_modes=0
definers='root@localhost'
client_cs_names='utf8'
connection_cl_names='utf8_general_ci'
db_cl_names='latin1_swedish_ci'
```

And for the trigger name file:

```
malff@linux-3ezv:test> more sale_tri.TRN
TYPE=TRIGGERNAME
trigger_table=product_sales
```

Multiple triggers in the TRG file will confirm if the definition somehow is corrupt (in which case you might have to drop and create the triggers again), but not how it actually became corrupt.

In any case, never edit `*.TRN` or `*.TRG` files manually.